# ApplicationRef.isStable not executing

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, rxjs-pipeable-operators, rxjs-observables

I'm attempting to write a service that measures the completion time of the app becoming stable.  Here's the service:

#### measure.service.ts

```js
import { ApplicationRef, Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { first, map } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class MeasureService {
  public constructor(private readonly applicationRef: ApplicationRef) { }

  public measure(): void {
    const startTime = Date.now();

    console.log(startTime);
    /**
     * Test stability metrics of application.
     */
    this.applicationRef.isStable.pipe(
      first(isStable => isStable),
      map(() => {
        /* tslint:disable-next-line:no-console */
        console.log("App stable ("+ Math.round((Date.now() - startTime) / 1000) + " secs)");
      })
    );
  }
}
```

#### app.module.ts (abbreviated):

```js
...
@NgModule({
   providers: [
      MeasureService
   ]
})
```

#### root.component.ts

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { MeasureService } from "../application-insights/measure.service";

@Component({
  selector: "mr-root",
  template: `
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  `,
})
export class RootComponent implements OnInit {
  public constructor(
    private readonly measureService: MeasureService
  ) {  
    this.measureService.measure();    
  }

  public ngOnInit(): void {
  }
}
```

The first `console.log` of the `MeasureService` correctly logs the time.  However, it appears the `applicationRef.isStable` never fires and, therefore, the second `console.log` never writes to the console.

Am I doing this right, or am I missing something?

Comment: I guess you missed one important thing... subscribe...

Comment: @yurzui ugghhh, my head hurts...that's my excuse for being so dumb :) thanks for catching my oversight!

Answer (score 2):

#### measure.service.ts (updated):

```js
import { ApplicationRef, Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { first } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class MeasureService {
  public constructor(private readonly applicationRef: ApplicationRef) { }

  public measure(): void {
    const startTime = Date.now();

    /**
     * Test stability metrics of application.
     */
    this.applicationRef.isStable.pipe(
      first(isStable => isStable)
    ).subscribe(() => {
      /* tslint:disable-next-line:no-console */
      console.log("App stable ("+ Math.round((Date.now() - startTime) / 1000) + " secs)");
    });
  }
}
```